# I have error 255 in return process

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstring>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int const MAX=10;
class Order{
int number;
char** ord;
int capacity;
int top;
public:
Order();
Order(Order const&);
Order (int);
~Order();
bool full() const { return top==capacity;}
bool empty()const { return top<=0; }
Order& operator=(Order const&);
void addItem1(const char*);
void cancel();
void Resize();
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os,Order const& q);
};

Order::Order(){
   number=0;
   ord=NULL;
   capacity=MAX;
   top=0;
}
Order::Order(Order const& w):number(w.number),ord(NULL),
                             top(w.top),capacity(w.capacity)
{
ord = new char*[top];
for(int i=0;i<top;i++){
   int k=strlen(w.ord[i])+1;
   ord[i]=new char[k];
   strncpy(ord[i],w.ord[i],k);
   ord[i][k-1]='\0';
}
}
Order::Order(int x):ord(NULL),top(0),capacity(MAX){
   number=x;
}
Order& Order::operator=(Order const& w){
     if(this!=&w){
       cancel();
       ord = new char*[top];
   for(int i=0;i<w.top;i++){
   int k=strlen(w.ord[i])+1;
   ord[i]=new char[k];
   strncpy(ord[i],w.ord[i],k);
   ord[i][k-1]='\0';
     }
  number=w.number;
  top=w.top;
  capacity=w.capacity;
return *this;
}
}
void Order::Resize(){
size_t Newcapacity=capacity*3/2+1;
char** tmp=new char*[Newcapacity];
for(int i=0;i<capacity;i++){
    size_t s=strlen(ord[i])+1;
    tmp[i]=new char[s];
    strncpy(tmp[i],ord[i],s);
    tmp[i][s-1]='\0';
}
for(int i=0;i<capacity;i++)
       delete[]ord[i];
  delete[] ord;

  capacity=Newcapacity;
  ord=tmp;
}
void Order::addItem1(const char* disc){
      //if(full())
        //    Resize();
size_t p=strlen(disc)+1;
ord[top]=new char[p];
strncpy(ord[top],disc,p);
ord[top][p-1]='\0';

top++;
}
void Order::cancel(){
   if(!empty()){
for(int i=0;i<capacity;i++)
        delete[] ord[i];
delete[]ord;
capacity=MAX;
top=0;
ord=NULL;
   }
}
Order::~Order(){
  cancel();
  number=0;
}
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os,Order const& t){
 os<<t.number<<endl;
 for(int i=0;i<t.top;i++){
    os<<i<<". "<<t.ord[i]<<endl;
 }
return os;
}
int main(){
int s1=257;
int s2=245;
int s3=244;
char S1[20]="Pile s oriz";
char S2[20]="Krem karamel";
char S3[20]="Salata";
Order p(s1);
p.addItem1(S1);
//p.addItem(S3);
//Order q(p);
//q.addItem(S2);
cout<<"First: "<<p<<endl;
//cout<<"Second: "<<q<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

Can s help me i dont know where is the error ?
I use Code::Blocks 10.05 if this matter.

```
0 errors, 0 warnings

Checking for existence: C:\Users\user1\Downloads\Нова папка\wtfff.exe
Executing: C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks/cb_console_runner.exe "C:\Users\user1\Downloads\Нова папка\wtfff.exe" (in C:\Users\user1\Downloads\Нова папка)
Process terminated with status -1073741510 (0 minutes, 8 seconds)
```

Comment: "i dont know where is the error ?" Why not? Didn't you use the debugger?

Comment: Have you tried running in a debugger? Because it could be that the program crashes, and running in a debugger will catch that crash and stop at the location of the crash. There you will be able to examine the function call stack as well as values of variables. If the debugger stops in a library function you can walk up the call stack until you get to your code. When you know where the crash happens in ***your*** code then mark out that line in the question, as well as showing the values of involved and relevant variables.

Comment: might I recommend the `std::string` and `std::vector`?

Comment: @txtechhelp please do. My eyes just melted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use constructor
`Order::Order( int x ) :ord( NULL ), top( 0 ), capacity( MAX )`
after that `ord = 0`

Error of access in function:
`void Order::addItem1( const char* disc )`

there you try to `ord[top]` in
`ord[top] = new char[p];`
but `ord = 0`

Comment: you need to `ord = new char*[top];` somewhere

Comment: Yes i didin't initialize anywhre ord....so at the function i try to see the information which is point by ord , but ord=NULL....Thanks a lot ..know it's working :)